# ActiveRecord callback access to session data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to add current user information to record using ActiveRecord callback, but I don't see way how to do that.
I tried Thread.current[:user], but in results I see that thread value is accessed from another user sessions.
I am using Passanger in production, but in the same time I am using acts_as_audited who get user value correctly.
Whats the best/safest way how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current user is not accessible from within an ActiveRecord model. This is due to the separation of concerns in Rails--the current user and the session are concepts that pertain to the realm of the controller.

You need to get the relevant data and pass it into the model in order for your callback to work. One way to do this is with an accessor method:

```
# model
attr_accessor :current_user

def my_callback
  # do something with current_user
  self.some_attribute = current_user
end

# controller
@model = MyModel.find(params[:id])
@model.current_user = current_user # assuming you have a controller method that does this
@model.save!
```

You should rename the `current_user` accessor to be meaningful: eg. if you are tracking the author of a blog post, call it `author` or `responsible_user` or some such, since `current_user` means nothing once the model is saved.

Comment: This way I already created, but it isn't flexible, because I set user only based on other attribute conditions. But for example how acts_as_audited (audited) do it based on application controllers method?

Comment: Sorry I've never used acts_as_audited. Perhaps you could add more detail to your question.

Comment: Ok, after ton of readings this is best way to keep MVC architecture clean. Thanks.